# write data to specific memory address issue

Tags: c, pointers

When I use the following code to write data at specific address at memory i get an error told me that

> " type error in argument 1" of function write.

as i understand `S_LEN` is a pointer to `0x1814` so it should work in correct way but at this case i get the previous error.

when i replace the command `write(S_LEN,0);` via `write(&S_LEN,0);` it work correct. although at first case i pass  hex number casting to pointer to integer.

can any one explain this matter?

```
#define RAM_START 0x1800
#define S_LEN  (((int32_t *)(RAM_START))[0xFF])
    int32_t write(int32_t *dest_ptr, int32_t src)
    {                                     
        *dest_ptr = src;
         return 0;
    } 

    main()
    {
     write(S_LEN,0);
    }
```

Comment: Why you dont using `mmap()` for memory allocation?

Comment: Please don't tag questions as both C and C++ unless you have a good reason. This is most likely a C question, and answers for C++ would differ greatly because they would recommend replacing the macros with something better, which isn't possible in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `write` function **expects** `int32_t *` as first argument, which is a **pointer**, so you should use something like this instead, if you want `S_LEN` to be a pointer:

```
#define S_LEN  (((int32_t *)(RAM_START))+0xFF)
```

Your expression evaluates to an `int32_t` since you apply the *subscript operator* `[]` on the `int32_t *` (which is a pointer).

On the other hand `&S_LEN` is accepted, beause it yields the address of the `int32_t` you get by applying `[]`.

Also note that `S_LEN` relates to the memory location `4*0xFF+0x1800` which is `0x1BFC`. (It is `255` `int32_t`s after `0x1800`).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `S_LEN` does the following:

1. it convert `RAM_START` to a pointer of type `int32_t *`
2. subscription of a pointer of type `int32_t *` should be a `int32_t` number

But `write` need first argument to be of type `int32_t *`, so `&S_LEN` is right, cause the address of an `int32_t` returned by `S_LEN` is of type `int32_t *`

The output from OSX 10.11:

```
[oxnz@rmbp:tmp:0]$ cc     a.c   -o a
a.c:14:8: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int32_t'
      (aka 'int') to parameter of type 'int32_t *' (aka 'int *'); take the
      address with & [-Wint-conversion]
        write(S_LEN,0);
              ^~~~~
              &(   )
a.c:5:16: note: expanded from macro 'S_LEN'
#define S_LEN  (((int32_t *)(RAM_START))[0xFF])
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:6:24: note: passing argument to parameter 'dest_ptr' here
int32_t write(int32_t *dest_ptr, int32_t src)
                       ^
1 warning generated.

[oxnz@rmbp:tmp:0]$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RAM_START 0x1800
#define S_LEN  (((int32_t *)(RAM_START))[0xFF])
int32_t write(int32_t *dest_ptr, int32_t src)
{
    *dest_ptr = src;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    write(S_LEN,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but, the first argument of the `write` function is pointer to int32